# User-defined vs. native ReactJS components

Tags: reactjs

Is there a good way to tell if a child is a user-defined ReactJS component or an "html" component (React.DOM.div, React.DOM.p, etc.)?

Comment: Why would you need to check for this?

Answer (score 1):

In React 0.12 you check if the "type" property is a string. In older versions you would have to inspect the "constructor" property (`child.constructor.name` would be a good hint)

```
var Element = <p>Some Tag</p>;
if (_.isString(Element.type)) console.log("got DOM primitive")
```